# Excel Dual Y Axis (one on top of the other)

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am wanting to create a line graph with the same variables, but two different machines. There are 16 total variables so overlapping 16 lines would look so messy. I don't want the user to have to copy and paste two charts at the end of each week to email, so I am wondering if it would be possible to create a chart like the one attached. Any help is awesome, thank you! [image: Single Side Dual Y Axis]

Comment: This almost certainly needs to be 2 charts. Rather than look for a way to hack this in a single chart (which almost assuredly will be insanely complicated to implement) why not just create a simple macro routine that copies/pastes the charts in to email? Or emails the entire worksheet/workbook?

Comment: Also, try taking the [tour] again and read up about [ask]. This question shows zero effort.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your feedback. I saw the macro export as an option, but I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing a simple solution to the idea above. And I'm not sure what you mean on the zero effort- I try to keep my posts as short and sweet as I can so it doesn't get confusing. (In the past I've often typed so many people lose track of what I'm trying to do!) I appreciate your help and feedback.

Comment: This is a site predominately geared towards solving programming-related problems, in *actually-existing code*. Your question doesn't seem related to programming at all (it's more of a SuperUser sort of question for Excel chart functionality), and if it is, you haven't shown any code nor given any indication that you've even attempted to solve this problem on your own. That's what I mean by "zero effort".  .

Comment: Ah, I gotcha. I apologize, I had added the VBA tag at the last minute to reference that I can do that, but was unsure how to go about it for this particular problem. I haven't posted to SuperUser yet, but now that I know that's where it goes, I'll be sure to post future questions there! Thanks for the clarification David!

Comment: @DavidZemens - The benefit to putting all of this into a single chart (in addition to the user not wanting people to have to hassle with two charts) is that the X axes can be aligned, so it's potentially easier to see where events are without having to line up two separate charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it may not be as pretty as you want. Just assign half the series to the secondary axis, then change the display ranges for the two axes. Here is how you figure out what to set them to.

Axis 1 minimum = Actual Data Minimum - Actual Data Maximum
Axis 1 maximum = Actual Data Maximum
Axis 2 Minimum = actual data minimum
Axis 2 maximum = Actual data maximum * 2

Since you have percentages in your example, this would be:
Primary axis minimum = -100%, maximum = 100%
Secondary axis minimum = 0%, maximum = 200%

Then you can play around with where the labels display etc to try to clean it up, but it won't look nearly as good as 2 charts (which you have ruled out).

Comment: Thanks, TTG Guy! I'll give that a go.